# Accessing Thumb.DragCompleted in Slider control

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have the following code which is used to control the media position of the MediaElement control.

```
<Slider Grid.Row="1" Maximum="{Binding TotalTimeStamp}" Value="{Binding CurrentTimeStamp, Mode=TwoWay}" Thumb.DragStarted="Thumb.OnDragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted=""Thumb_OnDragCompleted/>
```

For the purpose of seeking the video position within the MediaElement, I need to be able to pause the video when thumb drag has been started, and then resume the video once thumb drag has been completed. However, for some reason, I am unable to access neither DragStarted and DragCompleted of the Thumb control within the slider control, nor am I able to access the thumb control, even though diving into the Slider template shows that it does user a slider control.

Saying that, this was completely possible with WPF.

Comment: Have you tried checking for pointer or manipulation events or overrides?

Answer (score 0):

I played with the templates a bit, but it seems like you are right - if you drag the thumb - you get the drag events, but if you start dragging elsewhere - the best you can get is some pointer events. Maybe you could get somewhere with these, but it might be that you will simply need to throttle the events.

This is what I tried:

```
using System.Linq;
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions;
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

namespace App91
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            //WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions.VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetFirstDescendantOfType<>()
            var horizontalTemplateGrid =
                s1.GetDescendantsOfType<Grid>()
                .First(g => g.Name == "HorizontalTemplate");

            horizontalTemplateGrid.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            horizontalTemplateGrid.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
            horizontalTemplateGrid.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

            var rect =
                s1.GetDescendantsOfType<Rectangle>()
                .First(g => g.Name == "HorizontalTrackRect");

            rect.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            rect.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
            rect.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

            rect =
                s1.GetDescendantsOfType<Rectangle>()
                .First(g => g.Name == "HorizontalDecreaseRect");

            rect.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            rect.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
            rect.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved;

            var thumb = s1.GetFirstDescendantOfType<Thumb>();
            thumb.DragStarted += ThumbOnDragStarted;
            thumb.DragCompleted += ThumbOnDragCompleted;
            thumb.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            thumb.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
            this.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed;
            this.PointerReleased += OnPointerReleased;
        }

        private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs pointerRoutedEventArgs)
        {
            if (pointerRoutedEventArgs.Pointer.IsInContact)
            {
                DC.Trace("Pointer Moved");
            }
        }

        private void OnPointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs pointerRoutedEventArgs)
        {
            DC.Trace(
                "Pointer Released on " +
                pointerRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource.GetType() +
                " named " +
                ((FrameworkElement)pointerRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource).Name);
        }

        private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs pointerRoutedEventArgs)
        {
            DC.Trace(
                "Pointer Pressed on " +
                pointerRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource.GetType() +
                " named " +
                ((FrameworkElement)pointerRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource).Name);
        }

        private void ThumbOnDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs dragCompletedEventArgs)
        {
            DC.Trace("Drag Completed");
        }

        private void ThumbOnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs dragStartedEventArgs)
        {
            DC.Trace("Drag Started");
        }

        private void S1_OnValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DC.Trace("Value Changed");
        }
    }
}
```